# Как перетаскивать приложение без рамок. (Electron.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

Создаю первое приложение на Electron.js. Хочу сделать свои рамки приложения. Как убрать стандартные рамки я разобрался. Но как сделать так что бы приложение можно было двигать, зажимая определённый блок в html
.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Прошло много времени с вопроса, но эта первая ссылка в поиске и тут нет ответа.
Решение: HTML элементу нужно прописать css свойство:

```
-webkit-app-region: drag;
```